# Super Slow Docker Build

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I think I'm going to go crazy.  I've searched all over and can't seem to find a working solution both here on Stack, GitHub and other far reaches of the interwebs.

On this particular project, running `docker-compose build` is taking ***FOREVER***.  It didn't use to be this way, and on other projects that use Docker, it's not an issue at all.  And by forever... I'm talking around 10-15 minute build times when it used to only take around 2 minutes tops.  I had two separate coworkers DL the *same repo* (one on Ubuntu 18, and the other on macOS 14.x).  When they ran the `build` command, the entire process took ~2 minutes.  Both of these people had never built this project before, so they were starting from complete scratch.

I've uninstalled/reinstalled Docker, ran a complete `docker system prune -a`, connected via wifi, connected via Ethernet, tried a different wifi network, tweaked my compose file, tweaked my docker file -- nothing.

My machine is a 2018 MacBook Pro with a quad-core 2.7GHz i7, running macOS 10.14.6 with 16gb of installed RAM with Docker Desktop 2.1.0.5.

I've allowed Docker Desktop to have up to 12gb or RAM.  During the build process, my machine cpu usage spikes on average from 110% up to 270% running the `com.docker.hyperkit` process.

To be clear, it's hanging on the "Building php" (or "Building web") status message(s) before anything really even starts. After that, the actual build process runs smoothly and quick.

Here is my **docker-compose.yaml** file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    container_name: clientsname.db
    hostname: db
    image: mariadb:10.4.1-bionic
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database
      MYSQL_USER: my_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: my_pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my_pass

  php:
    container_name: clientsname.php
    hostname: php
    build:
      dockerfile: php/php.dockerfile
      context: ./
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=${REMOTE_HOST}

    volumes:
      - ../web:/var/www/web
      - ../moodle:/var/www/moodle
      - ../moodledata:/var/www/moodledata
      - ./php/custom.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zzz-custom.ini
      - ./php/z-errors.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/z-errors.ini:delegated
      - ./php/z-upload.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/z-upload.ini:delegated
      - ./php/z-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/z-xdebug.ini:delegated
    depends_on:
      - db

  web:
    container_name: clientsname.web
    hostname: web
    build:
      dockerfile: nginx/nginx.dockerfile
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - ../web:/var/www/web
      - ../moodle:/var/www/moodle
      - ../moodledata:/var/www/moodledata
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - php
      - db
```

Here is the referenced **php.dockerfile** file:

```
FROM php:7.2.26-fpm
LABEL maintainer="My Clients Name"

# Environment variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
ENV COMPOSER_NO_INTERACTION=1
ENV COMPOSER_HOME=/usr/local/share/composer

# Working Directory
WORKDIR /var/www/web
WORKDIR /var/www/moodle
WORKDIR /var/www/moodledata


RUN rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/no-debian-php && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
        build-essential     \
        php-soap            \
        libzip-dev          \
        libmagickcore-dev   \
        libmagickwand-dev   \
        libmagic-dev        \
        libpng-dev          \
        libfreetype6-dev    \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev       \
        libmemcached-dev    \
        zlib1g-dev          \
        nano                \
        sudo                \
        gnupg               \
        curl                \
        unzip &&            \
    docker-php-ext-install soap pdo_mysql mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd iconv && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && \
    pecl install zip-1.15.2 imagick memcached-3.0.4 xdebug && \
    docker-php-ext-enable memcached imagick zip xdebug

# Install Composer, Node, Gulp, and SASS
RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs && npm install npm@latest -g && npm install --global gulp-cli && npm config set unsafe-perm=true


# Export composer vendor path
RUN echo "" >> ~/.bashrc && echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

And the referenced **nginx.dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

RUN apk add --update bash && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

WORKDIR /var/www/web
```

It's driving me batty... what in the bloody hell could I be doing wrong?  If there is anything I've left out that you'd all like to know, please let me know and I'll update the post.

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @BMitch and you all who have commented thus far.  I took my entire /docker build directory and moved it into a test folder, and then created empty /web, /moodle, and /moodledata directories before running the `build` command.  It started to compile immediately.

What's curious to me is that the other coworkers DL'd the same Git repo that I have and did not have any of the same issues.  Oooh... come to think of it... I bet I know what the issue is.

Comment: I can build your php.dockerfile on Ubuntu@19.10 using Docker version 19.03.3, build a872fc2f8 just fine. Which version of both docker and docker-compose are you running?

Comment: `docker -v` and `docker-compose version` respectively

Comment: Docker 19.03.5 and Docker-Compose 1.25.1-rc1 just built the image in under 2 minutes

Comment: Just out of curiosity: will it get faster if you remove some of the volumes? If yes, are they maybe large or contain lots of files?

Comment: Are you able to build my LAMP stack? https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp

Comment: To answer @k0pernikus, I'm running docker 19.03.5 and compose 1.24.1

Comment: "Oooh... come to think of it... I bet I know what the issue is." ....well, what was it??

Comment: Hey Ken, what I thought it was, turned out to be completely wrong.  The answer from @BMitch below was the problem all along.  As soon as I ignored the /db-data directory... bam.  That was it.  Worked like a charm after that.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is from your build context (that's often the directory where you run your build, but can be overridden as you've done in the compose file). You have a large number of files, or large files, in the context directory that is sent before performing the build.

You can use `.dockerignore` which has a nearly identical format to `.gitignore` to exclude files from being sent on build. And with BuildKit (enabled if you `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` in recent versions of docker) it will only send context when you explicitly copy files and then only when those files have changed from what is available in the cache.

For more on the build context, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

There's also the best practices: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: Holy balls... that totally worked.  The problem was with the /db-data/ directory that was 9gb in size.  I had been looking in my /web folder and it never occurred to me that the problem was outside of the source folder.  Honestly, I had tried the .dockerignore route this morning after reading about it elsewhere, but I think I had the syntax just *slightly* off.  Thanks a million... I'll be sharing this info with the rest of our dev team and working it into our overall build process.

Comment: I had this issue too. My build => context directory was incorrect and it was taking 5 minutes before it would even start the build.

Comment: Very helpful advice! Make sure you use your project's `.dockerignore` to ignore things like logging folders containing gigabytes worth of log files from getting pulled into the build context unnecessarily (oops), and slowing the build down to a crawl.

You can also pass the `--verbose` flag to `docker-compose` to gain a little more insight into what it is doing, such as calling `docker-compose --verbose build`, which can help highlight which step it is "stuck" on.

Comment: Why should the file size make a difference to the build time though? I have 2TB of data on my laptop, build times are exactly the same as if I had 50gb. The data transfer step on Docker is usually lightening fast, just fyi.

Comment: @OliverDixon data transfer for a 1MB build context will be much faster than data transfer for a 20GB build context. Roughly 20,000 times faster.